# What is the difference between these three ways of redirecting to STDERR in bash?

Tags: bash

I have been using a warn function in bash for some time.

```
function warn { [ $# -gt 0 ] && printf '%s\n' "$*" >&2 ; }
```

But I've recently been told I should be using one of the following constructs.

```
function warn { [ $# -gt 0 ] && printf >&2 '%s\n' "$*" ; }
```

or

```
function warn { [ $# -gt 0 ] && printf >&2 -- '%s\n' "$*" ; }
```

I think I understand the `--` (if the parameters passed in contain a dash, it wouldn't be parsed as a parameter).

But what is the difference between the redirect being immediately after the `printf` or at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither suggestion is necessary. The problem `--` tries to solve is if you did something like

```
printf "$somestring" >&2
```

where `$somestring` could be mistaken for an option (and is not recommended for other reasons). `'%s\n'`, however, is not such a string. It is passed literally as argument to `printf`.

Moving `>&2` accomplishes nothing, since the shell removes it before trying to identify the arguments to the command.

If I were going to suggest any changes to your function, they would be

1. to drop the near-useless `function` keyword and use a POSIX-style definition instead.
2. Insist on a single argument with the warning message, instead of assuming the shell will join multiple arguments the way you want.

---

```
warn () { [ $# -gt 0 ] && printf '%s\n' "$1" >&2 ; }

warn "Do not do that"  # not warn do not do that
```

Answer (score 0):

No difference here. Redirections are special syntax interpreted and consumed by bash, the application does not observe these tokens in its command line. You can also precede the command with redirections, i.e. `>&2 printf ...`.